# AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials in .Net Core API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

can someone help me with this error that is happening. I don't know how to configure aws credentials.

My appliaction is .Net Core 2.0 API.

In localhost it works great since the file it is in a certain folder in C:/.

But when I am publishing it in IIS on a server its throwing error that is Unable to find credentials.

Here's the full error:
 An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials

Exception 1 of 3:
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Unable to find the 'default' profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain.
at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials(ICredentialProfileSource source) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs:line 72
at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs:line 112

Exception 2 of 3:
System.InvalidOperationException: The environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY/AWS_SESSION_TOKEN were not set with AWS credentials.
at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.FetchCredentials() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+coreclr\EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.cs:line 80
at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\_bcl+coreclr\EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials.cs:line 58
at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.<>c.<Reset>b__9_1() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs:line 55
at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs:line 112

Exception 3 of 3:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation timed out
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0):

On your local machine your AWS keys are stored in C:\Users\username\.aws\credentials file in the following format

```
[profilename]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You need to have access to this file on the server that is running IIS to add your credentials. If not possible, you will need to do one of the following:

1) Use IAM Roles to assign a role to the EC2 and launch it

2) Use Environment Variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html

> Environment variables. On a multitenant system, choose user
>   environment variables, not system environment variables.
>
> For more information about using environment variables to store
>   credentials, see Environment Variables in the AWS Command Line
>   Interface User Guide.

you can use  `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "XXXXX");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "yyyyyyy");`
  .NET API to create env variables from your C#/C++/VB code.

3) Use access key id and secret access key in the code or config files (not recommended)